# How to implement status LED in a system?

Tags: microcontroller, led, embedded

This question is related to general software embedded system practice. I want to have a blinking led as a status led for my MCU.

How correct is it to implement it with the timer interrupt? With that given the lowest priority.

How about using a PWM with some set frequency? Which method may have advantages over the other?

What is the general method that engineers in industry use for showing the status of system/mcu-unit using an led?

Comment: Generally engineers are building a circuit and writing the FW driving it. And they don't usually start the design from a status LED.

Comment: It depends exactly what status you want the LED to show.

Comment: Yes I understand. But once the firmware with target functionality has been written, what is the best practice to drive a status led? Like in an interrupt or PWM or somewhere in the main loop?

Comment: Say just blinking an led at some frequency.

Comment: It depends on the structure of your FW. If it has a fixed-time main loop - use main loop. If it is mostly interrupt driven - use interrupt. If it is multithreaded - use thread.

Comment: As Finbarr said, it depends on what status you want the LED to show. Do you want a status LED that blinks just to indicate that some status LED is blinking, or is there some other, perhaps less whimsical, information that you wish the blinking LED to convey? Related question: Why do you want it to blink as opposed to a solid light?

Comment: Blinking would tell me that the mcu is servicing interrupts correctly when I use it in interrupts. Also, blinking just naturally came to me because that is how we start off with any mcu. I am not very aware of how the industry uses led indication for status, thus the question. But I am open to ideas!

Comment: "Industry" is a broad term. Everything is depending on what the requirements are. One can decide to use the LED to send out the status as a Morse code.

Comment: Generally you'll already have a timer in your system for whatever the application is running at e.g. 10kHz, so you increment a counter in the interrupt routine and whenever it reaches a limit value toggle the LED.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I generally drive a status LED with various blink patterns, depending on the status of the system.  Each blink pattern lasts 1 second.

To define the patterns, I break the 1 second interval into time slices.  A mask of bits somewhere then defines whether the LED is supposed to be on or off for each time slice of each pattern.

This is not a critical task worthy of using interrupts for.  My standard status LED module contains a routine that can be called periodically.  It looks at the current 1 ms tick counter, and handles all timing accordingly.  As long as this routine is called often relative to the blink time slices, everything works seamlessly.  I usually call the routine from the main event loop when no other events were processed.  In other words, this is about the lowest priority thing the processor does.  That is completely opposite of using interrupts.

I do this often enough that I've got canned routines for this.  On Microchip dsPIC processors, I use 48 slices per blink pattern.  That's because program memory words are 24 bits wide, so 48 bits comes from using two words to define each blink pattern.  That means each slice is about 21 ms long.  The canned code uses whole ms ticks per time slice, but automatically varies between 20 and 21 ms to keep the whole pattern at 1 s in the long run.

Here is the template code for the STAT module on dsPIC processors.  You copy and rename this module into your project.  The QQn sequences get replaced with project-specific strings.

```
;   ***************************************************************
;   * Copyright (C) 2005, Embed Inc (http://www.embedinc.com)     *
;   *                                                             *
;   * Permission to copy this file is granted as long as this     *
;   * copyright notice is included in its entirety at the         *
;   * beginning of the file, whether the file is copied in whole  *
;   * or in part and regardless of whether other information is   *
;   * added to the copy.                                          *
;   *                                                             *
;   * The contents of this file may be used in any way,           *
;   * commercial or otherwise.  This file is provided "as is",    *
;   * and Embed Inc makes no claims of suitability for a          *
;   * particular purpose nor assumes any liability resulting from *
;   * its use.                                                    *
;   ***************************************************************
;
;   This module manages the status indicator LED.
;
;   The status indicator LED is blinked with a pattern dependent on system
;   status.  This module determines the blink pattern from the system status,
;   and performs the mechanics of blinking the LED accordingly.
;
;   Exported routines:
;
;     STAT_INIT
;
;       Must be first call into this module.
;
;     STAT_UPDATE
;
;       Must be called periodically.  It determines the system state, decides
;       what pattern to display, tracks real time, and updates the LED
;       accordingly.  It is intended to be called from the main event loop as
;       a low priority event.
;
;   Configuration parameters:
;
;     NAME
;
;       Name of the /OUTBIT pin that controls the LED.  Setting this line to ON
;       is assumed to enable the LED, and OFF to disable it.  The LED can be
;       wired either way, as long as the polarity in the /OUTBIT command is set
;       accordingly.  The default is "ledstat".
;
;     NSTBITS
;
;       Number of bits in a pattern.  The default is 48.
;
/include "qq2.ins.dspic"

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Configuration constants.
;
/const   name string = "ledstat" ;name of output pin controlling the LED
/const   nstbits integer = 48 ;number of slices in one-second display pattern

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//   Macro PATTNUM
//
//   Determine the number of the pattern to display.  This macro leaves the 0-N
//   pattern number in W0.  W1-W3 may be trashed.
//
/macro pattnum
         mov     #0, w0

havepatt:                    ;W0 contains the 0-N number of the pattern to display
  /endmac
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/include "(cog)src/dspic/stat.ins.dspic"

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Display patterns table.
;
;   Each display pattern must be defined here.  Patterns are defined
;   sequentially starting with 0 at TBL_PATT.
;
;   Each pattern is defined with the PATTERN macro.  The parameter to this macro
;   is a series of stars (*) or dashes (-).  A star represents LED on, and a
;   dash LED off.  There must be exactly NSTBITS total characters in the
;   pattern.  Patterns are displayed in left to righ order as defined by the
;   PATTERN macro parameter.
;
tbl_patt:
         pattern ************************------------------------ ;0 - normal operation

.end
```

This is the only code that requires customization.  Generally you only need to define the name of the output line that controls the LED, fill in the code that decides what pattern to display depending on system status, and the actual patterns.

Note heavy use of my PIC assembler preprocessor.  For example, the PATTERN macro used at the bottom makes defining patterns very easy.  The macro generates the actual .PWORD directives to define the pattern bits in program memory.  You could do that directly, but the PATTERN macro provides a much more intuitive interface to defining blink patterns.

For completeness, here is the code in the include file.  This is treated as a canned file and not modified per application:

```
;   ***************************************************************
;   * Copyright (C) 2005, Embed Inc (http://www.embedinc.com)     *
;   *                                                             *
;   * Permission to copy this file is granted as long as this     *
;   * copyright notice is included in its entirety at the         *
;   * beginning of the file, whether the file is copied in whole  *
;   * or in part and regardless of whether other information is   *
;   * added to the copy.                                          *
;   *                                                             *
;   * The contents of this file may be used in any way,           *
;   * commercial or otherwise.  This file is provided "as is",    *
;   * and Embed Inc makes no claims of suitability for a          *
;   * particular purpose nor assumes any liability resulting from *
;   * its use.                                                    *
;   ***************************************************************
;
;   Canned code for the STAT module.  See the header comments in the
;   QQQ_STAT.DSPIC file for a description of the possible configuration
;   parameters.
;

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Configuration constants.
;
/if [not [exist "name"]] then
  /const name string = "ledstat"
  /endif

/if [not [exist "nstbits"]] then
  /const nstbits integer = 48
  /endif
;
;   Derived constants.
;
/block
  /var local ii integer
  /var local r real
  /var local s string

  /const npattw integer = [div [+ nstbits 23] 24] ;N prog mem words per pattern
  /set r [/ 1000 nstbits]    ;ms ticks per display pattern slice
  /const add1ms integer = [rnd [/ 65536 r]] ;accumulator increment per ms
  /endblock

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Variables.
;
;*******************
;
;   Global state.
;
.section .stat,  bss


;*******************
;
;   Local state.
;
alloc    lastclock           ;last 1 ms clock value updated to
alloc    accslice            ;overflows when time for next display slice
alloc    slice               ;0-N current display slice number
alloc    pattn               ;0-N number of pattern being displayed

.section .stat_code, code
;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine STAT_INIT
;
;   Initialize the hardware and software state managed by this module.
;
         glbsub  stat_init, regf0

         mov     tick1ms, w0
         mov     w0, lastclock ;init last clock value current with
         mov     #65535, w0
         mov     w0, accslice ;force slice update next STAT_UPDATE
         mov     w0, pattn   ;init current pattern number to invalid
         mov     #[- nstbits 1], w0
         mov     w0, slice   ;first update will start at start of pattern

         leaverest

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine STAT_UPDATE
;
;   This routine is intended to be called periodically by the main event loop.
;   It determines the current system state, where it is within the current
;   display pattern, and updates the display accordingly.
;
;   Timing for the display is derived here from the global TICK1MS clock
;   variable.  This routine need not be called with any particular timing.
;   Since elapsed time is detected in whole ms, calling it faster than that has
;   no benefit, although it does no harm other than to take more excution
;   cycles.  Calling it less often than that will not cause time to be lost, but
;   will cause the display to be updated in bursts so as to appear to "stutter"
;   if too slow.  Roughly calling this routine every 1 to 5 ms is recommended.
;
         glbsub  stat_update, regf0 | regf1 | regf2 | regf3

stupd_recheck:               ;back here after a clock tick was processed
         mov     lastclock, w0 ;get last clock value updated to
         mov     tick1ms, w1 ;get the current clock
         cp      w0, w1
         bra     z, stupd_leave ;no new tick, nothing more to do ?
;
;   A new clock tick has occurred.
;
         add     #1, w0      ;update last clock value we are now current with
         mov     w0, lastclock

         mov     accslice, w0 ;update slice time accumulator to this new tick
         mov     #[v add1ms], w1
         add     w0, w1, w0
         mov     w0, accslice
         bra     nc, stupd_recheck ;no new display slice this tick ?
         ;
         ;   Advance to next display slice.
         ;
         mov     slice, w0   ;get the current 0-N slice number
         add     #1, w0      ;increment it
         mov     #[- nstbits 1], w1 ;get max slice number
         cp      w0, w1
         skip_leu            ;still within valid range ?
         mov     #0, w0      ;no, wrap back to 0
         mov     w0, slice
;
;   The display will be updated.
;
;   Determine the pattern to display.
;
         pattnum             ;set W0 to the 0-N number of pattern to display
;
;   W0 contains the 0-N number of the pattern to display.
;
         mov     pattn, w1   ;get number of pattern currently displaying
         mov     w0, pattn   ;update number of pattern to display now
         cp      w0, w1      ;compare new pattern to previous
         bra     z, stupd_hpatsl ;same pattern as last time ?
         ;
         ;   The display pattern has changed.  Reset to displaying the start of
         ;   the pattern.
         ;
         mov     #0, w0
         mov     w0, slice   ;set to first slice in pattern
         mov     w0, accslice ;set to start of this slice

stupd_hpatsl:                ;PATTN and SLICE all set
;
;   Update the display.  PATTN is the number of the pattern to display, and
;   SLICE is the 0-N slice to display within the pattern.
;
         ;
         ;   Init W3:W2 to point to the start of the patterns table in program
         ;   memory.
         ;
         mov     #tbloffset(tbl_patt), w2 ;init W3:W2 pointing to start of table
         mov     #tblpage(tbl_patt), w3
         and     #0xFF, w3
         ;
         ;   Update W3:W2 to point to the start of the selected pattern.
         ;
         mov     pattn, w0   ;get 0-N pattern number
         mov     #[* npattw 2], w1 ;get program memory addresses per pattern
         mul.uu  w0, w1, w0  ;make address offset for start of pattern
         add     w2, w0, w2  ;make start address of this pattern
         addc    w3, w1, w3
         ;
         ;   Skip over whole program memory words of the pattern to point W3:W2
         ;   to the program memory word containing the bit to display.
         ;
         mov     slice, w0   ;get 0-N slice number within this pattern
stupd_pwslice:               ;back here to skip whole prog mem words
         cp      w0, #24     ;compare to number of bits in a prog mem word
         bra     ltu, stupd_dpwslice ;done finding prog mem word of this slice ?
         sub     #24, w0     ;no, make 0-N number of bit within next word
         add     #2, w2      ;update address to next word
         addc    #0, w3
         jump    stupd_pwslice ;back to check slice within word again
stupd_dpwslice:              ;W0 is 0-N bit within word at W3:W2
         ;
         ;   W3:W2 is the address of the whole program memory word that contains
         ;   the bit to display.  W0 is the 0-23 number of the bit within that
         ;   word.
         ;
         mov     w3, Tblpag  ;set high bits of prog mem address to read from
         cp      w0, #16
         bra     geu, stupd_hword ;bit is in the high word ?
         tblrdl  [w2], w1    ;no, read the low word
         jump    stupd_hbits ;have bit pattern
stupd_hword:                 ;the bit is in the high word
         tblrdh  [w2], w1    ;read the high word
         sub     #16, w0     ;make bit number within this part of the word
stupd_hbits:
         ;
         ;   W0 is the 0-N number of the bit within W1 to display.
         ;
         lsr     w1, w0, w1  ;move the selected bit into LSB of W1
         btsc    w1, #0      ;bit is off ?
         jump    stupd_don   ;no, the bit is on

         set_ledstat_off     ;display off this slice
         jump    stupd_recheck

stupd_don:                   ;display on this slice
         set_ledstat_on
         jump    stupd_recheck

stupd_leave:
         leaverest

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//   Macro PATTERN patt
//
//   Create the table entry for one status display pattern.  PATT must be a
//   sequence of "*" and "-" characters.  "*" lights the LED for that time slice
//   and "-" makes it dark.  There must be exactly NSTBITS characters in PATT.
//
//   Patterns are displayed from left to right with a complete sequence lasting
//   one second.
//
//   This macro will emit .PWORD directives to define the data for the pattern
//   in program memory.
//
/macro pattern
  /var local patt string = [qstr [arg 1]] ;get the pattern string
  /var local ind integer = 1 ;1-N index into pattern string
  /var local pchar string    ;single character extracted from PATT
  /var local word integer    ;current program memory word being built
  /var local nbits integer   ;number of bits set within program memory word
  /var local ii integer      ;scratch integer

  /set nbits 0               ;init to no bits set in current word
  /set word 16#FFFFFF        ;init bits in current program memory word
  /loop                      ;back here each new bit in the pattern
    /if [> ind nstbits] then ;done all bits ?
      /quit
      /endif

    /set pchar [sindx ind patt] ;get the pattern character for this bit
    /set ind [+ ind 1]       ;update PATT index for next time
    /if [not [or [= pchar "*"] [= pchar "-"]]] then
      /show 'Invalid character "' patt '" in display pattern'
         .error  "Patt char"
         .end
      /stop
      /endif

    /if [= pchar "-"] then   ;set this bit to off ?
      /set ii [shiftl 1 nbits] ;make mask for this bit within word
      /set ii [~ ii]         ;make AND mask for turning off this bit
      /set word [and word ii] ;apply the mask to turn off this bit within word
      /endif

    /set nbits [+ nbits 1]   ;count one more bit done in current word
    /if [>= nbits 24] then   ;have a whole word to write out ?
         .pword  0x[chars [int word "fw 6 lz base 16 usin"]]
      /set nbits 0           ;reset to start of new word
      /set word 16#FFFFFF    ;reset word to all bits on
      /endif
    /endloop                 ;back to do next input pattern bit

  /if [> nbits 0] then       ;there are unwritten bits in WORD ?
         .pword  0x[chars [int word "fw 6 lz base 16 usin"]]
    /endif
  /endmac
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, having different led patterns to indicate different states of the MCU. Thank you so much Olin!

Answer (score 5):

The advantage of using a hardware peripheral, such as PWM or a timer, is that it does some of the work in hardware and frees up the MCU from having to do the work with instructions.

The disadvantage of using a hardware peripheral to indicate software status is that the hardware peripheral may continue to work after the software has stopped working and then the hardware-driven status indicator would indicate misleading status.

For example, after setting up the PWM an LED will flash without any software intervention.  That's nice because now the software can be simpler because it doesn't need to control the LED.  But the hardware PWM peripheral will continue to function as long as it's getting a clock.  It doesn't matter whether the software is running or has crashed.  So this PWM-driven LED is a bad indicator of whether the software is running.

Toggling the LED in a hardware timer interrupt simplifies the software because the software doesn't have to keep track of the time.  But now the flashing LED only indicates whether that hardware timer interrupt is working.  The main software loop or a task could be locked up but if the interrupt is still being serviced then the LED will continue to flash.  So this interrupt-driven LED is not a good indicator of whether the software is running.

If you want the flashing LED to be like a heartbeat that indicates that the software is running properly then you should control the LED flash from software.  And if you have a multi-tasking system with multiple tasks then the software should probably check the status of every task to determine whether the LED should be toggled.

I have used PWM or hardware timers to flash LEDs that indicate conditions (such as alarm thresholds), where flashing indicates the presence of the condition and off indicates absence of the condition.  Software still determines presence or absence of the condition and puts the hardware in the right mode, but then hardware controls the LED flash pattern while the condition is present.

Consider using a watchdog reset to not only reset the software in the event of a crash but also reset any hardware driven indicators.

Comment: Pointing out the hardware peripheral disadvantage was a great catch!  It was defeating the purpose of using a mcu status led. Thank you kkrambo!